# Intel I219-V (rev 20) on Ubuntu 20.04.3, exteremly slow wired connection

Tags: networking, drivers, internet, ethernet

I have a Lenovo Thinkpad P15s Gen 2i with an Intel Corporation Ethernet Connection (13) I219-V (rev 20) Ethernet Controller. My wired connection works fine on Windows. When I am running Ubuntu I get less than 2Mbs download speed with a wired connection. My wireless connection on Ubuntu works fine as well. I tried installing e100e-3.8.4.tar.gz and ice-1.6.7.4.tar.gz drivers and I still have the same outcome. Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Try third party drivers also. Maybe it is because of that. And mess with the ethernet settings. I had same problem but it got solved. I installed third party drivers. Try checking the developer's website for linux drivers.